# Do Gunnar glasses work for programmers?

Tags: productivity

(Is this the right forum)?

This is a question about Gunnar optics ([gunnars.com](http://gunnars.com))

I've seen some reviews, but I'm not quite convinced if they are for me. Some of the people reviewing are gamers, and I'm just a programmer. I do however spend a lot of time in front of my computer, and experience the eyestrain that they describe.

Does anyone have gunnars that program or perform similar tasks, that can verify that the gunnars work?

If so, what model should I get? Is it just a matter of taste and design or are there quality differences in what's best for my eyes?

Comment: You might want to look at [F.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/). Decreases the amount of blue as well.

Comment: Do "computer glasses" qualify as a computer peripheral equipment? :-)

Comment: @haimg - hell yeah!

Comment: This is a shopping recommendation, which unfortunately falls outside of the scope of this forum.

Comment: Only that we're not even a forum :) Seriously though, Jakob, this is something you may want to discuss on [chat], since we specifically disallow shopping questions, as @Randolph said.

Comment: I used forum in the traditional sense: "place of assembly" :-).

Comment: @slhck I'm afraid I haven't used it before. What "chatroom" should I enter?